# To distinguish between a Task and an Interrupt

Tags: c, interrupt

I have a point in my code where I need to check if program came here from an interrupt or a task. I am using SMX. Anyone used SMX can answer his question. I didn't get enough info from docs. So, basically I want some variable/parameter in order to distinguish between an ISR and a task.

Comment: ISR is different from task in many ways:

Processor will disable the Interrupt Enable flag IE to 0. So recursive interrupt is not possible.  

Before Jumping to ISR processor will save/push the status of the important registers like PSW, PC, and many more which is needed to save the current task. After completion this status will be pop back to main program. (switching context)

ISR doesn't have return value & arguments as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

Surely the code path is unique.  I don't know about SMX, but surely it doesn't override the usual mechanism whereby a function called by an interrupt has special handling to establish the stack frame, preserve registers, and maybe establish a static link to the module variables.  In such cases, the obvious means to check ISR vs. another route is for the ISR to set a flag at entry and clear it when it exits.